# Unable to connect to SSH server via Tor

Tags: ssh, proxy, tor

I'm attempting to connect to my SSH server via Tor on my rooted Android.

I couldn't find an SSH client for Android that supports the use of a SOCKS proxy, so I tried to use transparent proxying with Orbot for a number of SSH clients.

So far I've tested [JuiceSSH](https://juicessh.com/) and [Serverauditor](https://serverauditor.com/).

JuiceSSH seemed to have issues with my private key for SSH and Serverauditor just reported that the connection failed.

SSH via Tor works fine on my computer.

**edit:** I've manged to get the private/public key thing working with JuiceSSH and I've also tried to use ProxyDroid (can't hyperlink due to low reputation) to proxy all system traffic through Tor (SOCKS5, 127.0.0.1:9050).

JuiceSSH now keeps trying to connect but doesn't get much further. Serverauditor still just very briefly tries, then reports that the connection failed.

How can I connect to my SSH server via Tor, using private/public key authentication?